# How to Angular Convert S3 url path to Presigned URL

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I uploaded all my picture in my test bucket (

> https://vayup-test.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/

) 
all uploaded picture path inserted in my  database

> EX: /assets/userpoa/1549458226.jpg

My Bucket policy where Block all public access.
So I cannot render directly 
https://vayup-test.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets/userpoa/1549458226.jpg .

How to  generate Presigned using  Angular SDK.

Comment: `s3.getSignedUrl()`. This question has examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831829/nodejs-aws-sdk-s3-generate-presigned-url

Comment: How to do it in angular can you send me sample code